# C# WMI query to string

Tags: c#, string, textbox, label, wmi

I would like to output results from a WMI query to a textbox or label in C#.

But I get a `System.FormatException`, when I try to put result into a `textbox.text`.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();

scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\CIMV2");
scope.Connect();

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            
using (ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get())
{
    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
         //this line produces the System.FormatException:
         textBox.Text = string.Format("Computer Name: { 0}", m["csname"]);
     }
}
```

Comment: error message ?

Comment: Get rid of the space in the `{ 0}`

Comment: Fix the typo in your format string `Computer Name: { 0}` --> `Computer Name: {0}`.

Comment: Thanks to all, it was the typo. I'm sorry... maybe i sleep to less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your format string is that you have a space before the `0` in the placeholder: `{ 0}`. To fix the error, simply remove the space:

```
textBox.Text = string.Format("Computer Name: {0}", m["csname"]);
```

You could also simplify the code a little and use string interpolation (a C# 6 feature):

```
textBox.Text = $"Computer Name: {m["csname"]}";
```